Lower bound for $\max \{ |\pm z_1 \pm z_2 \pm \cdots \pm z_n| \} / (|z_1|+|z_2|+\cdots+|z_n|)$
Given a $n$-tuple of complex numbers $Z = (z_1, ..., z_n)$, define $M(Z) = \max \{ |\pm z_1 \pm z_2 \pm \cdots \pm z_n| \}$ among the $2^n$ possible combinations of signs, and $N(Z) = |z_1| + |z_2| + \cdots + |z_n|$.
I'm looking for a lower bound for $M(Z)/N(Z)$ among all possible $Z \neq (0, ..., 0)$.
For $n = 2$, I find that the minimum is obtained for $z_1=1, z_2=i$ and thus $\inf \{M(Z)/N(Z)\} = \sqrt{2}/2$.
For $n \ge 3$, I conjecture that the minimum is obtained with a sequence of consecutive isosceles right triangles, i.e.: $z_1 = 1$ and, for any $k \ge 2$, $z_k$ is orthogonal to the partial sum $z_1 + \cdots + z_{k-1}$ and has the same modulus as this sum.
For this configuration, we get $M(Z) = \sqrt{2}^{n-1}$ and $N(Z) = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}^{n-1} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}$, hence
$$\inf \{M(Z)/N(Z)\} \le \frac{(\sqrt{2} - 1) \sqrt{2}^{n-1}}{\sqrt{2}^{n-1} + \sqrt{2} - 2}.$$
In particular, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf \{M(Z)/N(Z)\} \le \sqrt{2} - 1$.
Is my conjecture the actual optimal configuration for $n \ge 3$? Otherwise, what is? And in both cases, how to prove the optimality?

+1 for an original question.

Can you tell us about the motivations for your conjecture? That might help answering.

@Andreas In the case $n = 2$, if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are not orthogonal and if, say, the angle $(z_1, z_2)$ is acute, the choice $|+ z_1 + z_2|$ is longer that the hypotenuse of the right triangle of sides $z_1$ and $z_2$. (Otherwise, choose $|+ z_1 - z_2|$.) So, in order to get the least value of $M(Z)$, $z_1$ and $z_2$ need to be orthogonal.
My conjecture for $n \ge 3$ is a blunt (but maybe wrong!) generalization of this phenomenon...

Using that $|x|+|y|\ge (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ one gets that $\sum |\Re z_k|+\sum |\Im z_k| \ge \sum |z_k|$ hence at least one of the sums on lhs is at least $1/2$ the sum of absolute values and clearly you can get least that in $|\pm z_1 \pm..z_k|$ by choosing the appropriate signs so the minimum is at least $1/2$ - hence not sure that your argument is correct since $\sqrt 2-1<1/2$

Your minimum stays at $\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$ unless you add a further constraint that the magnitudes of all of the numbers are approximately equal.

@Conrad You're damn right! My conjecture was totally flawed #shame: even for $n = 3$, my $(z_1 = 1, z_2 = i, z_3 = -1+i)$ does not reach its maximum for $|+ z_1 + z_2 + z_3| = 2$ since it can yield $|+ z_1 - z_2 - z_3| = 2\sqrt{2} > 2$!!

Expanding on the argument Conrad gave in the comments, we can get a bound
$$
M(Z)\geq \frac{2}{\pi}N(Z).
$$
For any choice of $u$ satisfying $|u|=1$,
$$
N(Z) = \sum \left(Re(uz_i)^2 + Im(uz_i)^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
For each $i$, we can choose a sign $\pm$ such that $Re(\pm uz_i)\geq 0$, and for these signs
$$
\left|\sum \pm z_i\right| \geq \sum |Re(uz_i)|.
$$
We can choose $u$ to try to maximize the quantity on the right. The average value of the right hand side over the set of all unit vectors is $2|z|/\pi$ (because $2/\pi$ is the average value of $|\sin|$). So there must exist $u$ and signs for which the right hand side is at least
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\sum|z_i|=\frac{2}{\pi}N(Z).
$$
This implies the stated inequality.
We can go further and conclude
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\frac{M(Z)}{N(Z)}=\frac{2}{\pi},
$$
and that taking $Z$ to be the $n$-th roots of unity exhibits this. Let signs $\pm$ be chosen so that $|m(Z)|$ is maximized, with $m(Z) : = \sum\pm z_i$. Write $u= M(Z) / m(Z)$, so $|u|=1$. Then
$$
M(Z) = um(Z) = \sum \pm uz_i = \sum Re(\pm uz_i) \leq \sum |Re(uz_i)|.
$$
If we take $z_i$ to be $n$-th roots of unity, then the rightmost term looks like a Riemann sum, and
$$
\frac{M(Z)}{N(Z)} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum |Re(uz_i)| \to \int_0^1 |\sin x|\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}.
$$

More generally, we could ask about $n$-tuples of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. A similar argument works if the function $z\mapsto Re(uz)$ is replaced by projection onto a $1$-dimensional subspace. The conclusion in this more general setting $\inf M(Z)/N(Z)$ has a lower bound independent of $n$, asymptotically sharp as $n\to\infty$, and that bound is the average value of $|x_0|$ over the $(n-1)$-sphere. If I calculated right, the bound is $(d-2)!!/(d-1)!!$ if $d$ is odd and $(2/\pi)* (d-2)!!/(d-1)!!$ if $d$ is even.

That's brilliant, thank you very much! If you happen to know some references related to this (kind of) problem, I'm interested.
Incidentally the moral of the story is that I should have followed my initial intuition and go on with the $n$-th roots of 1!

The small edit of your answer I've proposed has been rejected because it "deviates from the original intent of the post"!?
As a newbie on SE, I'm very eager to understand how it works. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with the edits below, please?
(1) Correct the last integral to $\int_0^1 |\cos(2 \pi x)|,dx$.
(2) On line 6, insert $= \left|\sum \pm u z_i\right|$ before $\geq$.
(3) Modify the sentence on line 7 to: "The average value (...) is $(2/\pi) \sum |Re(z_i)| $ (because $2/\pi$ is the average value of $|\cos|$)."
